# How to install Xencenter on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: software-installation, xen

I want to install Xencenter on Ubuntu 12.10. I've tried a lot of solutions, even Wine, but no luck this far. How do I install Xenceter on Ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: Well, for now, I'm working with OpenXenManager and I can't help but think that it is the best I'm going to get for now.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You can not. Wine [doesn't seem to work](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10094) so the only way is trhough a Windows VM.

However there's a similar opensource project called [OpenXenManager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openxenmanager/) wich emulates the one you mention.

### Install process

- Download OpenXenManager from sourceforge (link above) or

  ```
  wget http://freefr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/openxenmanager/openxenmanager_rev48.tar.gz
  ```
- Untar it manually or:

  ```
  tar xzf openxenmanager_rev48.tar.gz
  ```
- Install dependencies from the software center or:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install python-gtk-vnc
  ```
- Change current directory to where you extracted OXM:

  ```
  cd openxenmanager
  ```
- Run it:

  ```
  python whindow.py
  ```

---

There are also some other control/management/overview web based tools you could be interested in:

- [Xen Orchestra](https://xen-orchestra.com/) : prepacked vm ready to deploy on your xen server, it would serve a
- [XAC](http://hpieters.github.io/xac.js/)

OpenXenManager DOES look like XenCenter.

Comment: Can you explain how this is an answer to the question?

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Much better, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these intructions would be helpful to you, found at https://github.com/xenserver/xenadmin/wiki/Running-in-Wine

Only that SSL does not work so it is not advisable to use in a production network unless it is secured somehow. Maybe an isolated network direct to Xenserver. Or maybe have another program inbetween do the SSL part if there is such a thing.

```
apt-get install playonlinux
Run playonlinux
Tools -> Manage Wine Versions. Install wine 1.8.3 32-bit
Add a new program
Install to a virtual drive
Call it XenCenter
Select "Use another version of wine, configure wine, install some libraries"
"Use wine 1.8.3"
"Windows 7"
"32-bit windows installation"
POL_install_dotnet45, POL_Install_ie8, POL_Install_tahoma2
Install XenCenter
Connect to your XenServer, :80 due to SSL not working.
```